# Order in which our source code is run when using different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

When I first started learning about **Java**, I learnt that **code** is read from **top** to **bottom**. No need to make a code to cover that explanation as I guess you all understand it.

But what happens when I am using `multi-threading`? Say I have this simple example:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new WorkingClass());
        }
        System.out.println("rest od code..");
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}

class WorkingClass implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("working");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `singleThreadExecutor`, so **1 thread** should do those **5 tasks**. I was expecting that my **for loop** would run first, printing at least one `"working"` before printing `"rest od code.."` in **console**. I was wrong. My result is always this:

```
rest od code..
working
working
working
working
working
```

Can someone tell me how isn't at least one `'working'` printed in **console** before `'rest of code'`? Is it possible that code run so fast that it didn't get a chance to actually run any `run() method` before reaching ('rest of code')?

[NOTE] Any edit would be appreciated to help improve this question.

Comment: The overhead to create a new instance was probably slower than the current thread

Comment: You should run this multiple times to see if you get anything different

Comment: @OneCricketeer That is what I was expecting. I just didn't want to make any false assumptions so I don't learn something wrong. Yep I ran it multiple times :)

Comment: *FYI:* "I learnt that code is read from top to bottom." -- The compiler is allowed to reorder statements as long it doesn't change the result from a "single-thread-perspective" and other restrictions. That's not the cause of your "problem"; it's the thread-creation/scheduling overhead.

Comment: In multi-threading never assume the order of execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different threads run independently. There are no guarantees about relative order between your main thread and any of the 'Runnables' it creates.

This is nothing to do with whether code is 'read' from top to bottom; that's not a useful concept for execution. Here is a trivial non-thread example of non-top-to-bottom execution:

```
   void method1() {
       method2();
       System.out.println("one");
   }

   void method2() {
       System.out.println("two");
   }
```

Back to the issue at hand: you'll notice the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-) for 'execute' refers to running the Runnable at 'some time in the future'.

In reality, that's probably something like putting an entry on a queue and then waking up a thread.  Getting the thread up and running typically takes more machine instructions that the straight-line code path.

So, yes, your 'runs so fast' explanation is more-or-less on the mark, except that 'so fast' isn't really blindingly fast.

Comment: Makes sense. I think I am getting it. So there are 2 threads (main and thread1). In my case main thread just got to execute print statement faster than thread1 got to do any 'work', right?

Comment: Yup, exactly it.  The deeper lesson here is, if it's important for things to happen in a particular order (which it is not, in your case), then you have to make provision in code to force that order -- which is where the fun/horror of multithreaded programming comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Threads are executing concurrently (main thread and the worker thread), try pause the main thread execution for a short while before the println in main method, and the results will be different.

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("rest od code..");
executorService.shutdown();
```

Repeat the run and the chances that your worker thread execute while the main thread pause is highly likely.

What to expect is the memory consistency effect:

"Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable task to an ExecutorService happen-before any actions taken by that task , which in turn happen-before the result is retrieved via Future.get()"